# Is there an "on demand" bike hire scheme in Oxford?

Tags: rental, bicycles, oxford

Oxford is well known as a city with lots of cyclists, and (by UK standards at least) fairly good cycling infrastructure

Given that, and given how many tourists there are, I would've expected to find a bike hire scheme like in London or Paris, where you could rent bikes by the half hour on demand from docking stations.

However, I can't seem to find any such docking stations around any of the main tourist sites in the city centre. Is there a scheme?

Comment: I would dispute the claim that Oxford is known for (or has) "good cycling infrastructure". It's got a lot of cyclists, but there are no cycle lanes and very minimal cycle parking facilities (not to mention a very high level of bike theft). Unless you want to cycle for pleasure there's also no real reason to cycle in Oxford as a tourist; there's nothing to go to more than a twenty-five minute walk at most; the reason a lot of students cycle is for the extra five minutes in bed in the morning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is such a scheme. However, it doesn't yet cover the city centre, which is why you can't (yet) find any docking stations in the main tourist areas

The scheme is called [OxonBike](http://www.oxonbikes.co.uk/Info.aspx), and is run in conjunction with the county council.

Currently, all the docking stations are "up the hill", in and around Headington. They're around Oxford Brookes university, the hospitals and the like. A map of the stations can be found on the [OxonBike website](http://www.oxonbikes.co.uk/LocationsMap.aspx)

There's currently no announced date for when the scheme may extend down the hill and into the main tourist areas in the city centre.

Answer (score 1):

Brompton Bike Hire is also available in Oxford. The iconic foldable bikes are available from £2.50 a day.
http://www.bromptonbikehire.com/our-docks/oxford-2624/

Comment: Note that it's only available in from/to one place though, the station, which isn't all that convenient for some of the tourist sites